# Form doesn't accept additional parameters

Tags: python, django, django-forms, keyword-argument

I was trying to pass an additional parameter to my form, which is anObject to ForeignKey relation. But dunno why form returns `__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'parent'` when I'm pretty sure that it is possible to send additional parameters to form's `__init__` (ie here : [Simple form not validating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182262/simple-form-not-validating/3189499#3189499)). Am I wrong ?

```
def add_video(request):
    parent = ParentObject.objects.all()[0]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = VideoForm(data=request.POST, parent=parent)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()            
            next = reverse('manage_playforward',)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(next)
    else:
        form = VideoForm()

class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):       

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            self.parent = kwargs.pop['parent']
            logging.debug(self.parent)
        except:
            pass    
        super(VideoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

`kwargs.pop['parent']` is throwing `TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is unsubscriptable`, because you're trying to do a key lookup on a function method (`{}.pop`).  This error is then being swallowed by your exception handler.

For this to work do `kwargs.pop('parent', None)`.  In your case:

```
class VideoForm(forms.ModelForm):       
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.parent = kwargs.pop('parent', None)
        super(VideoForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

As a side note, 99% of time its best to only catch specific Exceptions in your except blocks.  Doing so will help dodge bugs/confusion like this.  Also, I would highly suggest adding unit tests for this custom construction (or just TDDing your other code, but that's a separate issue)

Comment: Yes,  the original code is pretty much an object lesson in why it's a bad idea to use bare exceptions.